# AOSP Lollipop build keeps hanging

Tags: android, android-source

I keep trying to build the latest Android source repository, but it always comes to a stop at one point, then it uses up just about all the system's RAM, and it keeps sitting there for hours without progressing one bit. It always comes to an end at about this line:

> target Java: Contacts
>   (out/target/common/obj/APPS/Contacts_intermediates/classes)

and when I Ctrl+C it, it always gives me this (sometimes among others, depending on how many threads I set for make):

> make: *** Deleting file
>   'out/target/common/obj/APPS/Contacts_intermediates/classes-full-debug.jar'

I'm trying to build aosp_shamu-userdebug on a Ubuntu 14, with open jdk 7. All over the net I found two similar questions to mine, but both had only the answers "you need more RAM". I was trying to build with 8 GB, last night i put in 8 more and left my PC to build this overnight, but come morning it had stopped at the same exact spot. I also tried building with no multithreading, in case that was the issue, but the result was the same.

Seeing as the problematic .jar has "full-debug" in it, I would suppose a "user" variant build might be successful, but it would be just about useless to me - I need to get a userdebug or eng running. However, if it would provide me with a jumping point to building what I need, I would of course try it.

Any and all suggestions on this matter would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Run make with 1 thread and the very last line will probably reveal the actual issue.

Comment: I regularly build Android AOSP on a Ubuntu 14 PC with 8GB RAM since long time and never had any issues related to system memory. I agree with @odexcide , try with single thread make

Comment: I forgot about having asked this question - the thing is I never managed to complete a build on this PC (not even with 1 thread), and neither could a colleague of mine on his - we finally found a build system in a a lot weaker laptop - but with a fresh Ubuntu installation. I suspect that having installed more than 1 JDK variants on the same Ubuntu creates some very complex issues, even removing JDKs and reinstalling openjdk7 didn't fix the issue - the Java installation and purge commands are probably not all they could be :)

Comment: Different versions of AOSP require different versions of the JDK (6 or 7) (openjdk or oracle). The most current version now requires openjdk. If you are building multiple versions, I would suggest using update-alternatives or update-java-alternatives.